# Is any specific handler required for http request of content-type : JSON on Apache?

Tags: json, apache, http-headers

My request header :

```
GET /abs/ad-content/id/1277954_1 HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

please note:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

But it seems my server can not process it.

```
$request->getHeader('Content-Type');
```

is returned empty by server.

Do I need to add some handler/Mime Type to get it work?

**Edit:** This header is present on my windows Apache localhost but missing on Bluehost Apache shared server.

Comment: I don't think apache comes in here unless you have some odd filter/.htaccess rule

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is not expected that a [GET request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.3) has a body as it is meant to be a [safe method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.1.1) only for information retrieval:

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
> HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
> other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".
> This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT
> and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the
> fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.

So I guess Apache or the programming language/framework you are using skips/omits any [entity header fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7.1) as it doesn’t expect any containing entity.

Comment: Vote up for explanation. But post request with some dummy post data is behaving same.